# How to hide a div element when scrolling up from any part of the page the svelte way?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to make my menu(div) appear only when the user scrolls up, so I wrote this code the svelte way, but it's not working... What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    let y;

    let newY = [];
    let oldY = newY[1];
    function updateY(y){
        newY.push(y);
         if(newY.length > 5){newY.shift()}
}
</script>
<svelte:window on:scroll ={updateY} bind:scrollY={y}/>

{#if oldY < y }
< div> ... content </div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off:

```js
let newY = [];
let oldY = newY[1];  // newY[1] is undefined
```

oldY will not be a reference to that position, even if it was set. If you want to update oldY when newY changes you can make it a reactive statement:

```js
$: oldY = newY[1];  // Each time newY changes, this statement will execute
```

Next:

```js
function updateY(y){      // y(Event) overshadows the locally declared and bound y(window.scrollY, a Number)
    newY.push(y);         // Is a mutation so svelte won't nofity changes
    if(newY.length > 5) {
        newY.shift();     // Again
    }
}
```

Mutations don't trigger reactivity, but it can be solved by simply inserting a `newY=newY;` statement to the end of the function. It is just a hint to the compiler that the state has changed.

Your final solution might look something like:

```
<script>
    let y;
    
    let newY = [];
    $: oldY = newY[1];
    
    function updateY(event){
        newY.push(y);
        if(newY.length > 5) {
            newY.shift();
        }
        newY=newY;
    }
</script>

<svelte:window on:scroll={updateY} bind:scrollY={y}/>

{#if oldY < y }
<h1>Test</h1>
{/if}
                         
<div></div>

<style>
    div {
        height: 200vh;
        background-color: red;
    }

    h1 {
        position: fixed;
        top: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Just to piggyback, if I wanted to increase the amount a person has to scroll before showing, all I have to do is increase newY.length from 5 to 20 or whatever number gives desired effect!